# Listbox showing wrong item (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I got a listbox with a number of rows, and a command button to show some of the columns from that row, in a seperate window (pop-up). The problem is that the row that it gets the information from (i.e. the row that is considered selected) is not the row that is currently marked, but rather the one that was marked before that.

So if I select row 5 and click the command button, it will just show a blank pop-up (no row selected). If I then select row 10 and click the command button, it will show the information for row 5, and so on. Is this a known issue or am I just doing completely wrong?

```
Private Sub cmdDetails_Click()
    'If the ListIndex is -1, no selection is made
    If lstItems.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No row selected", vbInformation, "No row selected"

    'If a selection is made, open the details form and fill in the details
    Else
        frmDetails.Show ' <-- Move this to the end of the sub

        With lstItems
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(i) Then
                    frmDetails.txtBox1.Text = .List(i, 0)
                    frmDetails.txtBox2.Text = .List(i, 2)
                End If
            Next i
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a multi-select? If not then `frmDetails.txtBox1.Text = .List(.ListIndex, 0)` with no loop or at least `Exit For` once you find what you are looking for.

Comment: It is not a multi-select, so you point on `Exit For` is valid. It has nothing to do with the issues I experienced though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited, possible solution at end of post*

I hacked your code listing into a quick comparison in Excel and am not having the same problem.  There are a few differences which may help you narrow down the source of the problem?  I used a single dimension listbox, and transferred that data into another listbox on the same form.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "No Row Selected", vbInformation, "No Row Selected"
Else
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                ListBox2.AddItem .List(i, 0)
            End If

        Next i
        End With
End If
End Sub

Public Sub FillMe()
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
    End With
End Sub
```

It appears that for the most simple case, the code you listed seems to be working, so that at least eliminates off by one bugs, and seems to indicate what you have listed is working as expected.  I'm not sure how far you've gone into the problem but..

- Add Breakpoints and verify the index value is what you are expecting (or not)
- Verify the loop doesn't evaluate true two separate times, overwriting the original value
- Verify routine is only triggered one time using breakpoints

I realize the above is standard debugging, but hopefully it is helpful.  I am going to create a second form and pass the data between the two just to see if it makes a difference.  Will edit post if I find anything useful.

------Edit------
I think your problem may lie with how you are populating a second form.  It appears that Excel may halt code execution in the first thread when you hit the userForm.Show routine.  That would prevent text boxes from being populated.  Then when you close your second box, the fields get populated with the first set of data.  When you try again, code execution halts at the Show, and you see the previous results.  As for the proper work around, still working..

-----Edit with answer ------

Two possible solutions,  first off, simply move your lstDetails.Show to directly after the For statement:

```
If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "No Row Selected", vbInformation, "No Row Selected"
Else
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                UserForm2.newListBox.AddItem .List(i, 0)
            End If
        Next i
        End With
UserForm2.Show
End If
```

Second solution would be to instantiate a local version of the form, populate it, and then display it.  Basically it's the same solution, just slightly different method of implementation.

```
Dim newForm As New UserForm2
If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "No Row Selected", vbInformation, "No Row Selected"
Else
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                newForm.newListBox.AddItem .List(i, 0)
            End If
        Next i
        End With
newForm.Show
End If
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If the selected values are just going into a text box, then shouldn't multi-select should not be used and `Exit For` should be inside the `If .Selected(i) Then` statement.

Comment: An Exit would shorten code execution so yes, it would be an improvement.  I chose to leave it as is, to approximate the original problem as closely as possible.  As it turns out, the For statement was not the root of the problem, so I left it as is.

Comment: You were right about the `frmDetails.Show` halting the code execution. I moved it to the end of the sub, and everything works as intended. So much head ache for such a tiny thing. Thanks for saving me :-)